# tikz used to generate eddies in oceanographic diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I m attempting to generate several curved paths with an arrow at the end:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5}
\draw [>=stealth, <-] (\x,4.1) arc (0:280:.1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you can see that this doesn't look quite right i.e. the arrows don't look right. I'm not sure if this is due to the curved path being to big or the arrow head being too big? I cant seem to work out the problem, but essentially I would like to make these so that the curved arrows represent eddies in an oceanographic diagram I am generating. I hope I have been clear in my intentions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem comes from the path being small relative to the size of the arrow head.  However, you can adjust the arrow heads direction by drawing the circle the other way round starting at `280` ending at `0` and adding a short straight segment afterwards for the placing the arrow.  This extra end point can be nicely specified using the `+()` syntax for relative coordinates.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5}
  \draw [>=stealth,->] (\x,4.1) arc (280:0:.1cm) -- +(283:0.05cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```